# How can i add, read and edit a PDF document in Flutter?

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, pdf, mobile

Im currently working on an app for civil engineers that contains the user's different projects and their "building plans".
In one of the screens im supposed to create, there is one where the app will load the building plan (which is a pdf document) and the user can move around (up,down,left&right) and add a "Reserve", which is essentially a small numbered circle that will either overlay the pdf or will be coded and saved to it.
Important to mention that um using MongoDB for the backend.
I have never used pdf manipulation in flutter before, and by now means im a flutter expert, i looked around the net but couldnt find anything that was close to what i need, tried different tutorials, packages and codelabs but couldnt get the needed result.
Attached are UI captures of the interfaces i need.
Literally ANY help would be appreciated.
[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Z1a.jpg)
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpsrC.jpg)

Tried syncFunction PDF for Flutter,
tried David Gonzalez's tutorial on Medium.com

Comment: Ikr! Yes that is exactly what i need, a plans viewer with mark up functions. However, as per the client's request, the user can only use it on PDF files, and not on AutoCad files such as DWG